# How to download and read all pages from web site that have more than one page?

Tags: python

I need to get all city names from this site
http://www.geonames.org/advanced-search.html?q=&country=BH&featureClass=P&continentCode=

So I have writing this python code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function

from zipfile import ZipFile
import glob
import sys, os
import requests, re

S = requests.Session()


City_Code = 'BH'

url = b"http://www.geonames.org/advanced-search.html?q=&country=%s&featureClass=P&continentCode=".decode("utf-8") % City_Code


def main():

            
    data = S.get(url, verify=False).content
    print(data, file=open("output.txt", "a"))
    regx='''<a href="(.*?)"><img src="/img/20px-Wikipedia-logo.png"'''
    match = re.findall(str(regx), str(data), re.M|re.I)
    print(match, file=open("output2.txt", "a"))
    cities = []
    for cityURL in match:
        #if 'wiki' in cityURL:
        #        continue
        cityName = os.path.split(cityURL)[1].replace(".html","").split("_%", 1)[0].split("%", 1)[0]
        print(cityName, file=open("split.txt", "a"))
        if cityName in cities:
            continue
        cities.append(cityName)
    cities.sort()
    return cities


if __name__=='__main__':
     main()
```

But the problem is the code does not print and print all city names and I have got only 34 names and should by I get more than 100 names

```
Manama
Al_Muharraq
Riffa
Hamad_Town
Dar_Kulaib
Sitra
Isa_Town
Jidhafs
Al_Hidd
Galali
Zallaq
Shakhura
Jasra
Budaiya
Tubli
Sufala
Sanad
Salmabad
Marquban
Karbabad
Jurdab
Jaww
Jannusan
Dumistan
Bu_Quwah
Barbar
Bani_Jamra
Nuwaidrat
Al_Qadam
Al_Markh
Janabiyah
Hamala
Ghuraifa
Diraz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs for each page change in a very structured way so you can use this to iterate through them all. I've updated your code to go through the first 20 pages and grab the first 1000 cites. You can extend it further by changing the pages np.arange(0, 1001, 50)

```
import numpy as np

url = b"http://www.geonames.org/advanced-search.html?q=&featureClass=P&startRow=".decode("utf-8")
pages = np.arange(0, 1001, 50)

cities = []
for page in pages:
    ##Change the startRow in the URL
    url_2 = url.replace("startRow=","startRow="+str(page))
    request = requests.get(url_2)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        print('Web site exists')
        data = S.get(url_2, verify=False).content
        print(data, file=open("output.txt", "a"))
        regx='''<a href="(.*?)"><img src="/img/20px-Wikipedia-logo.png"'''
        match = re.findall(str(regx), str(data), re.M|re.I)
        print(match, file=open("output2.txt", "a"))
        for cityURL in match:
            #if 'wiki' in cityURL:
            #        continue
            cityName = os.path.split(cityURL)[1].replace(".html","").split("_%", 1)[0].split("%", 1)[0]
            print(cityName, file=open("split.txt", "a"))
            if cityName in cities:
                continue
            cities.append(cityName)
        cities.sort()
    else:
        print('Web site does not exist')
        break
```

Comment: Can you try running "import numpy as np"? The rerun the code?

Comment: I have replace it with range as like this pages = range(0, 1001, 50) and work but still I cannot get full names of city .... I will try other countries ..

Comment: Did you move this "cities = []" outside of the loop? I was able to get 1000 cities using that.

Comment: no I did not remove any thins ...Now I try with (GB - United Kingdom) http://www.geonames.org/advanced-search.html?q=&country=GB&featureClass=P&startRow=0 and I change this pages = range(0, 2001, 100) Then I have got (968 names of citys) ... Do you think that correct result ?!!

Comment: No, I think it should be pages = range(0, 2001, 50) because the URL changes by 50 each time.

Comment: Ok.. Now .. one more things .. can you check this country http://www.geonames.org/advanced-search.html?q=&country=DZ&featureClass=P&continentCode= (some country contain unicode characters) and the result of names not correct like for example (A%C3%AFn_El_Hadjar%2C_Sa%C3%AFda) and I have got just (A) ... Thank you